# Change text in Commerce Kickstart "order total" dynamically

Tags: 7, commerce

I want to change the label in the attached image, that is from Commerce Kickstart. I need to change that text depending on the role of the user.

If the user has **role1** then the text will be "**order total**" & if user has **role2** then the text should change to "**Quote total**". Any idea?

I tried to debug with Devel to see where to change the label but I could not find it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `hook_commerce_price_formatted_components_alter()`
The following example checks if VAT has been applied to the order total and changes the string accordingly:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_price_formatted_components_alter().
 *
 * Alters somes text at the checkout form
 *
 * @param $components
 * @param $price
 * @param $entity
 */
function mymodule_commerce_price_formatted_components_alter(&$components, $price, $entity) {
  $pieces = explode('/',current_path());
  if(!isset($components['tax|ch_vat']) && $pieces[0] == 'checkout'){
    $components['commerce_price_formatted_amount']['title'] = t('Order total (excluding VAT)');
  }
}
```

Comment: IT worked!! could you tell me how did you find the right hook?

Comment: Many sleepless nights :) The modulename.api.php file usually contains the module's hooks. From then on, it is a matter of experimenting

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to implement `hook_entity_view_alter()` in a custom module of yours.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULE_entity_view_alter(&$build, $type) {
  switch ($type) {
    case 'commerce_order':
      /**
       * In here implement your alter logic
       */
      break;
  }
}
```

To determine what exactly to alter, after the *'in here...'* comment you can use `debug($build);` or `dpm($build);` (if devel installed).

To see the user roles:

```
global $user;
debug($user->roles);
```

Similar issue [here](https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/2370/additional-information-order-page).

Comment: It would be really nice if people who downvote answers explain why.